# formik react arrays are always slow to response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I have a react form which uses formik, which works fine in terms of all the information is handled. but all my child elements that handle child elements eg tag picker file selector etc, all have a delayed response time, which makes it look like you have to double click them.

eg in my tag picker i use an autocomplete input text box to get the tag options, and when i click the tag i want, it doesnt work for about 2 seconds, which is a real issue.

i have tried adjusting the way my information works, but i am starting to think its a rendering issue but not sure how to work out the real issue or fix the issue.

Any suggestions would be appriciated.

Comment: have you tried to change <Field /> (s) to <FastField /> ?

Comment: I am not using Field at all, am using html inputs the actual updates are find, its just the time it takes to allow a user action, eg i type in text for the auto complete and allow me to choose on the results takes seconds (neither of these are formik form elements, i have just noticed on the same form when I add a row and update one field and then update another it has the same issue and these are formik issues, so i am now thinking its not a formik issue but I still have no idea how to fix it